# How do you draw square arrows, either above or below from the center of one element in an equation to the center of another?

Tags: math-mode, equations, arrows, underline

I have checked other answers, but they are not easily customizable to get the desired behavior. They do not center the ends of the arrow and do not support underlined text in the equation.

I have this example equation:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}
$\lambda \underline{x}.((x\ y)\ \lambda z.(x\ z))$
\end{document}
```

The goal is to be able to draw a square arrow from center of `\underline{x}` to the center of the first x that follows it. The square arrow needs to be able to go above or below the equation, and the distance from the equation up or down needs to be specifiable too.

Comment: Please embed your code snippets, i.e. add the "few" missing lines to make your math compile. Also try to include your best trial to introduce such arrows: you wrote you read about them, at least. This will improve answers and keep your question from an early close votes. Thank you

Comment: To all the users. The user have put the MWE.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit tedious and involves compiling twice, but the following code works

```latex
    \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc} 
    \newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
    \begin{document}
    $
    \lambda \tikzmark{a0}\underline{x}\tikzmark{a1}.\tikzmark{b0}x\tikzmark{b1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \coordinate (amid) at ($(a0.south)!0.5!(a1.south)$);
        \coordinate (bmid) at ($(b0.south)!0.5!(b1.south)$);
        \draw[->, to path={-- ++(0,-.25)  -| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes},below,pos=.25]  (bmid) to (amid) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    $
    \end{document}
```